# How to print only first word after the equal sign

Tags: bash, shell, unix

[image]

Input file(present in `/sys/test/list.txt`):

```
"BA_FN" = "John"    <<NEW>>

"BA_ACCOUNT_NO" = "AACtesting56"    <<NEW>>

"BA_BILLINFO_ID" = "BULCA8-67"    <<NEW>>

"BA_LN" = "winslet"    <<NEW>>
```

I need to print only below values using shell script:

```
John

AACtesting56

BULCA8-67

winslet
```

Can someone help me pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the content is in file sample.txt and it looks like

```
"BA_FN" = "John"    <<NEW>>

"BA_ACCOUNT_NO" = "AACtesting56"    <<NEW>>

"BA_BILLINFO_ID" = "BULCA8-67"    <<NEW>>

"BA_LN" = "winslet"    <<NEW>>
```

we can print with below command

```
cat sample.txt |awk -F"=" '{split($2,a," ");gsub(/"/, "", a[1]);print a[1]}'
```

output will be

```
John

AACtesting56

BULCA8-67

winslet
```

Comment: Thank you suhas it works as expected..

Comment: You can avoid use of cat here but doing `awk ....... <filename>`

Comment: Hi guys, What if i want to print like:
BA_FN = John

Comment: How to print:
BA_FN = John
BA_ACCOUNT_NO = AACtesting56
BA_BILLINFO_ID = BULCA*-67
BA_LN = winslet

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
awk '{print $3}' sample.txt | sed 's/"//g'
```

output:

```
John

AACtesting56

BULCA8-67

winslet
```

To break it down:

`awk` by default separates every field by spaces. Each line of `sample.txt` has 4 fields. In the first line:

- 1st field `"BA_FN"`
- 2nd field `=`
- 3rd field `"John"`
- 4th field `<<NEW>>`

Since you need the 3rd field printed: `awk '{print $3}'`

`sed` in this example works likes this:

sed `'s/pattern/replacement/g'`

So in this instance `sed 's/"//g'` is simply removing all occurrences of `"` and replacing them with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cat /sys/test/list.txt | cut -d "=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| sed 's/"//g'
```

and will show:

```
John

AACtesting56

BULCA8-67

winslet
```

but if you want suppress the empty lines, you can try this.

```
 cat /sys/test/list.txt | cut -d "=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| sed 's/"//g'| grep -v "^$"
```

this will show:

```
John
AACtesting56
BULCA8-67
winslet
```

Comment: You can avoid use of `cat` here.

Answer (score 0):

split with `"`

```
awk -F '\"' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

How about good old grep `grep` ,if you do not care much about empty lines : This will print anything between `" = "` and `" <>`.

```
grep -oP '(?<=" = ").*?(?=" <>)' inputfile
John
AACtesting56
BULCA8-67
winslet
```

Or you want to preserve , empty lines between records then:

```
awk '{gsub(/\"/,"",$3);print $3}' inputfile
John

AACtesting56

BULCA8-67

winslet
```